# Replacing * with \* in Clojure

Tags: string, clojure, replace

How do I escape `"*"` to `"\*"` in clojure? Can't seem to get it to work:

`(s/replace "A*B" #"*" "*")` produces  `"A*B"` (of course)

`(s/replace "A*B" #"*" "\*")` fails: `Unsupported escape character: *`

`(s/replace "A*B" #"*" "\\*")` produces  `"A*B"` again!

`(s/replace "A*B" #"*" "\\\*")` fails: `Unsupported escape character: *` again!

`(s/replace "A*B" #"\\\\*" "*")` produces  `"A\\*B"`

I can't get it to produce `A\*B`
Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use 4 backslashes:

```
> (println (clojure.string/replace "A*B" #"\*" "\\\\*"))
A\*B
nil
>
```

or, without a regex, it's simply:

```
> (println (clojure.string/replace "A*B" "*" "\\*"))
A\*B
nil
>
```

---

To use this as a regex pattern, use the [`re-pattern`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/re-pattern) function:

```
> (def p (clojure.string/replace "A*B" #"\*" "\\\\*"))
#'sandbox17459/p
> (println p)
A\*B
nil
> (clojure.string/replace "BLA*BLA" (re-pattern p) "UH")
"BLUHLA"
>
```

Comment: That only works when you print the result:  
    user=> (clojure.string/replace "A*B" #"\*" "\\\\*")  
"A\\*B"
user=> (clojure.string/replace "A*B" "*" "\\*")  
"A\\*B"  
  
I have to use the result in a regex. I don't want to print it.

Comment: I want to replace "BLA*BLA" to "BLA\\*BLA" - this exact string. Saddly, the example you gave me does not work....

Comment: OK. So you want to use a regex to create another regex pattern? Could you give an example of your input, the regex pattern you expecting, and the result you expect?

Comment: I have string containing a list of jvm options from Glassfish. One of them is something like this: -blabla,excludes=*com/sun/corba**/*. I need to to find this text in the list.

Comment: *I want to replace "BLA*BLA" to "BLA\\*BLA"*: `(clojure.string/replace "BLA*BLA" #"\*" "\\\\*")` does this. Just for clarification, note that you can't just have a string literal like `"BLA\*BLA"` with the \ flowing around. The \ changes the meaning of the following char, turning it into an escape character. Hence the \ *has to be escaped itself inside the string*. If you want to use the string `"BLA\\*BLA"` as the regex pattern `BLA\*BLA`, you have to use the `re-pattern` function, since `"BLA\*BLA"` is not a valid string (since \ is not a valid escape character in strings).

Comment: Also, ` (println (clojure.string/escape "A*B" { \* "\\*" }))`