# How to remove a backslash \ from string Clojure

Tags: string, clojure, character, backslash

I've tried several ways but I still can't get it to work.

```
 (clojure.string/replace "[\"fish\"]" "\\" "")
```

I want it to be "["fish"]"

I've also tried .replaceAll

The problem is I don't know how to pass in the \ into the parameters. I've looked at the answer suggested here:

[Replacing * with \* in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834063/replacing-with-in-clojure)

which is referring to adding the \ instead of removing, but this didn't work for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the uselessly short answer is you are not able to remove them because they are not there to be removed.

Lets step through the evaluation of the expression above:

1. first it reads the string `(clojure.string/replace "[\"fish\"]" "\\" "")` as a bunch of characters and parses it into a list. that looks like (function-name string1 string2 string3)

   - string1 = ["fish"] (note that there are no \'s they where consumed by the reader)
   - string2 = "\" (again no extra \'s)
   - string3 = ""
2. then it evaluates that expression by calling the function, which because the input contains no \s it just returns it unchanged.
3. then it prints the result in a format suitable to be read back in. To make this code safe to read, it has to **escape the "s by adding \s** as it writes them to the screen.

at the repl we can see this if we print the output for human consuption instead of computer consumption:

```
user> "[\"fish\"]"
"[\"fish\"]"
 user> (println "[\"fish\"]")
["fish"]
```

or

```
user> (println (clojure.string/replace "[\"fish\"]" "\\" ""))
["fish"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I could't understand what exactly you want your result to be, but if you are trying to parse the given string and expect your output to be a vector then you can use clojure's `Cheshire` to parse string like this:

```clj
(vec (cheshire.core/parse-string "[\"fish\"]" )))
;; ["fish"]
```

If you want a simple string result then you can use the above answers/solutions.

Answer (score 2):

`"[\"fish\"]"` *is* "["fish"]"

The quotes are [escaped](https://clojurebridge.github.io/community-docs/docs/clojure/string/). If your string was literally "[\"fish\"]", it would look like `"[\\\"fish\\\"]"`.

In that case

```
> (clojure.string/replace "[\\\"fish\\\"]" #"\\" "")
"[\"fish\"]"
```